# Fast Image Downscaling in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, image-resizing

I'm looking for fast C/C++ libraries to perform fast downscaling using mainly linear and cubic interpolation. Are FreeImage and/or FFMPEG libswscale good alternatives. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Unless you're going to be downscaling only factors less than 2 (i.e. never making the image smaller than half its original dimensions), linear/cubic interpolation are completely wrong and will result in horrible aliasing artifacts. You should use area-averaging or a gaussian filter with sufficiently large radius. `libswscale` offers both of these and more options, and it's by far the fastest you'll find.

Comment: @R. that's true of naive implementations of linear/cubic interpolation, but it's possible to scale those formulas to get them to behave properly for larger downscaling factors. Area-averaging would be my choice for best compromise between fast and acceptable quality.

Comment: By definition, linear interpolation is simply a weighted average of two point samples. This inherently results in aliasing when whole input samples or even whole ranges of input samples are not used whatsoever in the output.

Comment: **VIPS** seems to be a good contestant especially when it comes to a combination of high speed and low memory usage. Has anybody compared it with `libswscale`? See http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=VIPS and benchmarks at http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=Speed_and_Memory_Use

Comment: Don't use FreeImage scaling, it has great encoding and decoding performance, but has horrible scaling performance (but good quality!)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at imagemagick?  http://www.imagemagick.org/